# Disabling Maven Dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I'm having a strange problem with my project. There are two dependencies in my POM.xml that belong to my company's repository that I would like to delete and replace them with others that are in my local machine . However, when I do, the maven build fails with the following error:

```
Error:(21,27) java: unmappable character (0xE9) for encoding UTF-8
```

All I did was delete the two dependencing from POM and from classpath and replace them with the libraries in my local machine.

Could somebody please tell me why the build fails when I delete them from the POM, as if the encoding was depended on them?! And most importantly, if I can't delete them, is there a way I could keep in the POM all while disabling them?

I tried to edit the libraries themselves by addng:

```
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>Path/to/the/local/library</systemPath>
```

But Maven didn't like it:

```
'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin @ line 865, column 21
Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter. @
```

Comment: You can comments Maven dependencies

Comment: Please add the complete error output.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time. I had to fix every unmappable character separately and manually to get past the error.